# What is the darwinssl library location on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, curl, darwin

I am trying to compile curl and statically link it to another project.
I did manage to compile it for my mac architecture(x86_64) and got "libcurl.a".
Now when I try to build:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
  CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
}
```

with g++ tornado.cc -o tornado   (path-to-where-it-is)libcurl.a -std=c++11

I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      _append_cert_to_array in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
  "_CFArrayCreate", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_step2 in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
  "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
  "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      _darwinssl_connect_common in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
  "_CFDataCreate", referenced from:
      _append_cert_to_array in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-darwinssl.o)
```

As I understand it wants to get links for darwinssl, but I do not know where to get those.

The readme for curl (https://github.com/biasedbit/curl-ios-build-scripts/blob/master/README.md) - does mention it depends on libz.dylib and
Security.framework but does not give any clues about what they are, when and how do I need them, and how to include those.

P.S. the regular curl inclusion works fine: `g++ tornado.cc -o tornado -lcurl -std=c++11`

Comment: Actually it looks like it needs functionality from the Foundation framework. What happens if you add `-framework CoreFoundation` to `gcc`? Edit: If it says it depends on libz and Security, then try `-lz -framework Security`

Comment: it did not make the difference

Comment: Consider installing Macports and using `sudo port install curl`.  It will save you tons of time.

Comment: Did you try reordering `-lz` and `-framework Security` around? Edit: So the full command would be
`g++ tornado.cc -std=c++11 -o tornado path/to/libcurl.a -lz -framework Security`

Comment: reordering did not help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found some time to mess around on the mac. Here's the command that worked for me:

```
gcc main.cpp -I path/to/include path/to/libcurl.a -framework Foundation -lz -framework Security
```

Basically, you need `-framework Foundation`, `-lz` and `-framework Security`.